# If div is visible then toggle icon

Tags: jquery

How to toggle the icon class from `fa-chevron-down` to `fa-chevron-up` on link if the `toggle-project-stages` div is visible?

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/bQ8G3/125/)**

```
$(".toggle-project-stages").hide();

$(".toggle-project-status-downArrow").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var toggleDiv = $(this).parent().prev('.panel-heading').find(".toggle-project-stages").toggle(200);

    $(".toggle-project-stages").not(toggleDiv).slideUp(200);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass)

```
$(".toggle-project-stages").hide();

$(".toggle-project-status-downArrow").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var toggleDiv = $(this).parent().prev('.panel-heading').find(".toggle-project-stages").toggle(200);


    $(".toggle-project-stages").not(toggleDiv).slideUp(200);
    var $i = $('i', this).toggleClass('fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up')
    $('.toggle-project-status-downArrow i').not($i).removeClass('fa-chevron-up').addClass('fa-chevron-down')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wj4hx6wn/)

Comment: Lovely! That made it! Thank you so much! I am marking this one as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".toggle-project-stages").hide();

$(".toggle-project-status-downArrow").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var toggleDiv = $(this).parent().prev('.panel-heading').find(".toggle-project-stages").toggle(200);
    if( $(this).children().hasClass( "fa-chevron-down" )){
        $(this).children().removeClass('fa-chevron-down').addClass('fa-chevron-up');    
    }
    else{
        $(this).children().removeClass('fa-chevron-up').addClass('fa-chevron-down');    
        
    }
    
   
    
    $(".toggle-project-stages").not(toggleDiv).slideUp(200);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="panel-dashboard">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="toggle-project-stages">
            <p>This is what I want to show!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="toggle-project-status">
        <a href="#" class="toggle-project-status-downArrow">Show div <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>

<br/><br/>

<div class="panel-dashboard">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="toggle-project-stages">
            <p>This is what I want to show!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="toggle-project-status">
        <a href="#" class="toggle-project-status-downArrow">Show div <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the callback of `toggle()` you can use `toggleClass` to remove the `chevron-down` and `chevron-up`. Try this:

```
$(".toggle-project-status-downArrow").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $el = $(this);
    var toggleDiv = $el.closest('div').prev('.panel-heading').find(".toggle-project-stages").stop(true).toggle(200, function() {
        $el.find('i').toggleClass('fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up');
    });
    $(".toggle-project-stages").not(toggleDiv).stop(true).slideUp(200);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bQ8G3/128/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I tried your suggestion and it's nearly there. The arrow should go down once I click on another link. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/bQ8G3/129/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".toggle-project-stages").hide();

$(".toggle-project-status-downArrow").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var toggleDiv = $(this).parent().prev('.panel-heading').find(".toggle-project-stages").toggle(200);
    $(".toggle-project-stages").not(toggleDiv).slideUp(200);

    var $i = $('i', this).toggleClass('fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up')
    $('.toggle-project-status-downArrow i').not($i).removeClass('fa-chevron-up').addClass('fa-chevron-down')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-dashboard">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="toggle-project-stages">
            <p>This is what I want to show!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="toggle-project-status">
        <a href="#" class="toggle-project-status-downArrow">Show div <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>

<br/><br/>

<div class="panel-dashboard">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="toggle-project-stages">
            <p>This is what I want to show!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="toggle-project-status">
        <a href="#" class="toggle-project-status-downArrow">Show div <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```